# InputSystem behaves differently in Build and Editor

Tags: unity, input

I'm trying to map WASD, Arrow Keys and Gamepad Left Stick to camera movement.

[image]

So `A`/`Left arrow` is negative, `D`/`Right arrow` is positive.

I've had issues with the UI trying to consume those key presses, so for the moment I've deleted all UI actions and disabled event consumption.

I'm polling the axes in a method invoked from Update():

```
private void HandleInput() {
        var movementInput = new Vector2(
            plumbing.Controls.GalaxyMap.MoveLeftRight.ReadValue<float>(),
            plumbing.Controls.GalaxyMap.MoveUpDown.ReadValue<float>());
        HandleMovement(movementInput);

        var rotationInput = new Vector2(
            plumbing.Controls.GalaxyMap.RotateLeftRight.ReadValue<float>(),
            plumbing.Controls.GalaxyMap.RotateUpDown.ReadValue<float>());
        HandleRotation(rotationInput);

        //Debug.LogFormat("Move {0}, Rotate {1}", movementInput, rotationInput);
    }
```

This works perfectly in the editor, however, when I build the game, pressing `A` results in moving right when it should move left. Pressing `D` *also* moves right.

Left arrow works as expected, but both A and Left arrow are configured identically...

[image]
and
[image]

The debug output shows that MoveLeftRight.ReadValue() is returning +1 for the axis when it should be -1.

There are no other indications anything is wrong/unusual.

Why is it flipping one half of the axis at runtime? How can I prevent this?